# Vue is not initialized (laravel)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

After the running of:

```
npm install
npm  run watch
```

in the folder resource/js do not have initialized vue example.

my package.json have the follow dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.24.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
 }
```

I expected to have something like this in file app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example- 
component',require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app'
});
```

instead i only have

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

can someone help me?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Have you created <div id="app"></div> in blade?

Comment: Laravel Framework: 6.9.0

Comment: yes but nothing changed @Yurich

Comment: Did you include the scripts provided in the default blade layout file?

Comment: yes, but still not works